# play framework passing a custom tag action link @{}

Tags: tags, playframework

I am trying to figure out how to build a simple custom tag (for learning purposes)
My goal is to build a simple form tag, so when i need to i can use it in the following way `#{simpleTag params.. /}`.

simpleTag.html

```
<form name="input" action="${_action}" method="get">
            ${_inputTitle} <input type="text" name="${_varName}" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

my  main issue is  - in the above code the `action="${_action}"` i would like to use the reverse lookup notation instead, Such as `action="@{_somthing}"` but how can i pass such parameter to tag in play framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you try something like this:

```
%{ action = play.mvc.Router.reverse("SomeController.someAction")}%
#{simpleTag action:"${action}"/}
```